# Can I use toString to convert an Array identifier to a string?

Tags: javascript

Using the below array of objects I want to convert just the array identifier "Giants" to a string.

But every bit of code that I have attempted is returning a string of the entire array. I have gone back and forth across the internet but have not found anything stating something like this which seems so simple. So it leads me to think I am missing something really obvious here.

```
let Giants = [{
        name: "Manning",
        power: 99,
        position: "QB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Toomer",
        power: 85,
        position: "WR",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
];
```

Comment: Yes, returned as a string.  In the tutorials I have read they have called a variable name an identifier.

Comment: Got it, I think the linked question is the same and it has a couple of answers.

Comment: *Why* do you want this? These seems likely an XY problem, e.g., you don't want a variable named `Giants`, you want an object with a `Giants` key, with the players under that.

Comment: I don't think that's possible? 

You want to get "Giants" as a string output somehow using only the variable Giants above?

Comment: I had posted question number 63766749 that is in some way the opposite, where I eventually want an HTML input string to convert to the array name, for the purpose of having that array be used in a loop that returns pts, that can be used for whichever team has the ball. In the case of this question, I want to use whatever array name is in the loop in a string at the end that says <arrayNameTeam> + "has 20 pts."

Comment: I suppose I see what @Dave is saying in that I could add a key called `TeamName: Giants` within the array, and then call for that in the string. `TeamName + "has x pts`.

Comment: @KevinO'Neill No, I'm saying you have an object with a `Giants` key, and retrieve the team members that way.

Comment: @DaveNewton. OK, I will go back and review the parts of an object to better understand that.  I am a little confused by keys and properties and from what I am reading it seems like two different terms for the same thing. If not I go back to the comprehension drawing board.

Comment: I found this question on Stack. It helped.
[**Properties vs. Keys vs. Values in JavaScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648090/properties-vs-keys-vs-values-in-javascript)